# Issue with displaying the Jquery Ajax response in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I need to load a page where that page needs to display some values with a dynamic pagination. So to load the values I have a rest call, In that rest call I am returning a json object. In the browser console I am able to see the json output. Now My issue is I am getting the response on `$document.ready()` function. Now I am trying to display the json object values in the HTML which is not happening.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
           url : "http://localhost:8080/school-service/school/list/students/1/1",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "json",
          }).done( function(studentList) {
              console.log("AJAX request success:" +studentList.pageNumber);
            }).fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              console.log("AJAX request failed with status:" + textStatus);
          });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="next"><img onclick='previousPage("${studentList.pageNumber}", "${studentList.pageCount}")' src="${context}/images/previous.png"></a>


        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${studentList.pageCount}">
            <a href="${context}/school/list/students/1/${i}" id="${i}" class="pages">${i}</a>
         </c:forEach>

<a href="#" class="prev"><img onclick='nextPage("${studentList.pageNumber}", "${studentList.pageCount}")' src="${context}/images/next.png"/></a>
```

Can anyone please help me that how can I display the json response object value in HTML.

Comment: Is `console.log("AJAX request success:" +studentList.pageNumber);` return anything?

Comment: Yes it is returning "AJAX request success:5"

Comment: Okay and where you want to display the response object values in your HTML.

Comment: In the for loop and a tag. Where ever I am using ${studentList.pageNumber} and ${studentList.pageCount} in my above code.

Comment: Check my answer @Vinod.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't because the code you want to replace in your page is belong to a server-side language (i guess `asp`) and server-side code will be compiled before javascript execution so you'll not found the tags those tags.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand what you are trying to do, you are trying to get the value from your AJAX request and include the returned value from .done in the html?

If that is the case, check this link out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

If you are returning a JSON object from .done, you will need to parse the JSON object into a string in order to place it in the DOM. From that point, you will need to decide where it should be placed.  For example, you can create a div and say $('that-div').append(returned value).

Another approach could be having a default value in the html, and on .done, replace the html by calling .html on your response.  But to do that you will need to grab a reference of $(this).

I hope this helps, if not let me know where my gaps are and we can go over this in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you write is a server side code with JSTL, and it is not available when the AJAX response is returned.

1. JSP page will be converted to HTML.
2. The HTML page will call the server by using AJAX.
3. The returned response is a JSON which is received in a Javascrip Object.
4. You need to do some javascrip work to make your `a` tags

You need to write some Javascript code to render the returned response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
int pageCount = studentList.pageNumber;
```

Then in your html simply do this

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end=studentList.pageNumber>
        <a href="${context}/school/list/students/1/" + i id=i class="pages">i</a>
     </c:forEach>
```